# "one" as a pronoun for uncountable nouns

Tags: pronouns, uncountable-nouns

Is it grammatically right to use **one** as a pronoun to substitute for the word **water**?

> I prefer plain water to sparkling one.

Comment: No. Although if they were countified by using indefinite pronouns, one could say _I prefer a plain water to a sparkling (one)_; the final _one_ is optional. As it is, you could say _I prefer plain water to sparkling_ with nothing; indeed _I prefer plain to sparkling_, in context (say, at a store, with the cold drink door open), requires no noun or pronoun at all.

Comment: The point is that "one" is a common noun that has an antecedent which is not a full NP. Your example would thus mean "I prefer plain water to sparkling plain water", which makes no sense.

Comment: BillJ, by your logic, "_I prefer a plain water to a sparkling one_." is incorrect, because means "_I prefer a plain water to a sparkling plain water_." Could you explain it? Thanks!